# netbeans 6.9 rake error on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, netbeans-6.9, ubuntu-11.04

Each time I try to run a brand new rails project in Netbeans I get the following error:

"Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)"

What's happening?

P.S: I already did a bundle install and if I run "ruby s" from the console it works.

Thx.

Comment: Are you using rvm, by chance?

Comment: I got the same while creating a project in RubyMine! Couldn't figure a solution yet.

Comment: Having exact same problem using rvm and bundler. Have done manual gem installs, checked paths everywhere, it IS there but for whatever reason that's the only one that it whines about

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the same manually, i.e from the terminal. First check which version of rails you are running, then try to bundle again from the terminal.

I suppose that your environment selected in netbeans does not recognize the latest rails gem but is using another one. Check with rails -v to see which version of rails you are running. If it is ok in the terminal, make sure you are running netbeans with the same user (ex. sudo or your user depending on the rvm config you have).

I had this problem several times with different IDE and every time it was because I was not using the proper user or not using the proper gemset in RVM (it's so easy to forget !)

After that it should be easy to resolve by choosing the right environment in the config of your project in netbeans or rubymine.

Comment: Brilliant! It works in the terminal. The terminal in my IDE doesn't handle it right, but the OS terminal does. Thanks!